# Custom Ruby Gem in Gemfile on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've modified a Gem that I use in my Rails app, and need to use it on Heroku. Is there a way to upload the modified Gem to Heroku within my app and specify a custom path in my Gemfile?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can place custom gems in the `vendor` directory and then specify them in your Gemfile:

`gem 'gemname', '1.0', :path => 'vendor/gemname'`

Comment: this is to change for Rails 4 see your deprecation warnings...

DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

Comment: yes, actually you can put gem anywhere you want and specify that path in Gemfile.

Answer (score 9):

in Gemfile:
`gem 'blah', :git => 'https://github.com/XXX/YYY.git'`

Answer (score 8):

1. Fork it on github
2. Point your application to your modified gem using :git option when specifying gem dependency in Gemfile

Comment: Gems from github include the full history. Over time it will take up lots of space (think 30mb instead of 3mb). It's fine for a few gems, but over time will add up.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a custom gem server like [Geminabox](https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox). Unfortunately, it is designed for a LAN and has no built-in authentication.  You can protect it via Rack::Auth middleware or use Rack::Mount to attach it to a secret path.  If that's too tedious, you can use a private gem hosting service like [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com) (disclaimer: I work on this service).  Once you have either of those set up, just add the following to your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://custom-gem-server.com/secret-token/'
```