# How does the production environment in Rails / Heroku work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to learn Rails by making a blog for myself and deploying it on Heroku, but I'm encountering a NoMethodError on a custom gem.  Everything is working locally in Development, but I keep encountering errors when moving to Production.

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.1ms)
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `bbcode_to_html' for #<String:0x000000032ee278>):
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:    <p class="article_body"><%= raw Post.last.body.bbcode_to_html %></p>
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div id="homepage_headline">
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: </div>
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:    <h1 class="article_title_headlines"><%= link_to "#{Post.last.title}", post_path(Post.last) %></h1>
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-18T02:17:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/home/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__3063155323426577095_38919220'
```

I've included bb-ruby in my Gemfile like so:

```
group :production do
    gem 'thin'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'bb-ruby', '0.9.6', :path => 'vendor/bb-ruby'
end
...
gem 'bb-ruby', '0.9.6', :path => 'vendor/bb-ruby'
```

I've tried requiring bb-ruby in the view, but then Heroku gave me a file not found error.

I guess my main question is this: what's the difference between production on Heroku and development on my machine?  Other than what I can tell from the evironments' config files.  All I know so far is that Heroku requires assets like javascript and css to be precompiled.  But what about gems?  I haven't been able to find a very good explanation about how to use custom gems in Heroku. I appreciate any help.

UPDATE:  I've been able to get the app to work properly by using version 0.9.5 of bb-ruby. Version 0.9.6 was a version I created myself (working in development) but is causing problems in Heroku, I think because I packaged it myself and specified the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use your own custom version, fork the gem in github, make your own changes, and then use the :git option in your gemfile to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify path, Heroku overrides this and the default is fine unless you know better.  You also want pg and bb-ruby without a specific group since you need it everywhere.

Comment: I tried pushing to heroku without the specifying the path, but the push was rejected because heroku "Could not find bb-ruby-0.9.6 in any of the sources", which is expected as 0.9.5 is the latest available (0.9.6 is my custom version)

Comment: I was following the instructions on this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800074/custom-ruby-gem-in-gemfile-on-heroku