# ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

Can someone tell me why I'm getting the following error?

This is my `states_controller.rb`:

```
def index
    @states = State.all
end
```

And in index.html.erb:

```
17 <form>
18    <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
19        <option>Select State…</option>
20    <% @states.each do |state| %>
21        <option value="<%= state.id %>">
22        <%= nytimes_state_name(state.name) %></option>
23    <% end %>
24 </select>
25 </form>
```

This works fine when I run it locally, but once deployed to Heroku, I get the following error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)`

When I remove the `nytimes_state_name` method, it runs fine until it hits the next block:

```
46 <% @states.first(25).each do |state| %>
47 <li><%= link_to state.name.downcase + nytimes_state_abbrev(state.name), state %></li>>
48 <% end %>
```

And then I get the same error.

And again, when I remove `nytimes_state_abbrev` method, it works fine until it hits the next block of code, which also calls `state.name` and expects it to be a string. (The `name` values are postal code abbreviations—`CA`, `AZ`, `TX`, `NY`, and so forth.)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same gem versions both locally and on Heroku? Try running locally with bundler, i.e. `bundle exec rails server`.

Comment: It's still running fine locally, but you did remind me that I had to modify the gem to avoid an instance variable collision with my `states` model. How do I deploy the modified gem?

Comment: That's a whole different question. :) The short answer is either embed the source directly in your Rails app (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800074/custom-ruby-gem-in-gemfile-on-heroku), or fork the gem on Github and reference the fork in your `Gemfile`. Basically, put it somewhere Heroku can see it.

Comment: @dpassage's suggestion did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124939/actionviewtemplateerror-no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer#comment40945854_26124939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer as to why OP was seeing different behavior on his local build and on Heroku was because he had made modifications to one of the gems he was using, and those modifications weren't getting pushed when he deployed.

The solution is to either embed the source of the gem directly in your Rails app, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800074/custom-ruby-gem-in-gemfile-on-heroku), or fork the gem on Github and reference the fork in the `Gemfile`. Sounds like he chose the former, and now has consistent behavior between his local build and Heroku.